# Make a new directory and copy a file into the folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I use a date variable to create a new folder like this:

```
@echo
cd \
D:
cd "D:\My Projects\Test"
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") DO MD "NPP file backup %%g%%e%%f"
:END
```

It gives me this result:
D:\My Projects\Test\NPP file backup 20240125

How can I specify the newly created folder as the target destination in a copy command?  I want to incorporate it into the my batch file.

File is located here:
"C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Roaming\NPP\Shortcuts.xml"

I tried:

```
set target="D:\My Projects\Test\NPP file backup %%g%%e%%f"
COPY "C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\NPP\Shortcuts.xml" %target%
```

It's not working at all.  Certainly no expert with batch scripting, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a one line batch-file example: ```@For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe " 123"') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%AppData%\NPP" "D:\My Projects\Test\NPP file backup %%G%%H%%I" "Shortcuts.xml" 1>NUL```.

Comment: I have no idea how that works, but that's pretty cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%e`, `%%f`, and `%%g` stop existing when the `for` loop ends. If you want to be able to use these values later on in the script, you'll need to store them in a regular variable.

```
@echo off
cd /d "D:\My Projects\Test"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do set "target=NPP file backup %%g%%e%%f"
mkdir "%target%"
copy "%appdata%\Notepad++\Shortcuts.xml" "%target%"
```

Comment: Thank you! that works perfectly. The initial batch file I created above was pieced together by 'googling' around for a solution so I did not fully understand what was going on. Thanks for your helpful explanation and quick answer. 

EDIT:

Actually I have a quick follow-up question.  I noticed in your answer you did not include :END  at the very end of the script.  Your script works fine so I know it is unnecessary but I have also seen :EOF in some other scripts on this forum.

So it begs the question, when is :END (or :EOF) necessary in a batch script?

Comment: @M4verick: `:eof` is built-in to `cmd` to mean `physical end-of-file`. Reaching end-of-file terminates the script or if a subroutine is in progress, the subroutine. `:end` is used when the programmer doesn't know anout `:eof`

Comment: And as a slight elaboration, the script will automatically end when it runs out of code to run, so neither `:END` nor `:EOF` is ever necessary. If you want to end the script before the natural termination of the code, you can use the command `exit /b`.